# Plotting a particles's trajectory

Tags: plotting, calculus-and-analysis, physics

I need a little help in plotting a trajectory.

A particle moves along a trajectory such that its radius vector is given by:

$\qquad r[t] = A(e^{\alpha t} + \widehat{e_1} + e^{-\alpha t} + \widehat{e_2})$

where A and $\alpha$ are constants, graph the trajectory, so

```
r[t_] := A (Exp[α t] + Exp[-α t]);
sol1 = Limit[r[t], t -> Infinity, Assumptions -> {α < 0, A > 0}]
sol2 = Limit[r[t], t -> Infinity, Assumptions -> {α > 0, A < 0}]
```

effectively gives infinity, any idea how to make the plot?

Comment: whats $\hat e_1$ and $\hat e_2$?

Comment: $\widehat{e_2} and \widehat{e_2} $ is index notation for vector calculus, example $\widehat{e_1} = x i $ and $\widehat{e_2}= y j $

Comment: I don't see this as a valid equation. It adds scalars to unit vectors.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My interpretation of the comments is that you're working in cylindrical coordinates where the radius $r$ is $\hat{e_1}$ provided by the formula in your question, the angle $\theta$ is $\hat{e_2}$, and height $z$ is $\hat{e_3}$. Then we have a helix / whirlpool / tornado-like trajectory:

```
With[{A = 3.0, α = 0.08},
 With[{r = A*Exp[α t] + Exp[-α*t], θ = A t, z = A t},
  ParametricPlot3D[
   {r Cos[θ], r Sin[θ], z}
   , {t, 0, 30}, PlotRange -> All]
  ]]
```

[image: tornado]

Answer (score 4):

Make use of

```
PolarPlot[2 Exp[.3 t], {t, 0, 2 \[Pi]}]
```

[image: PolarPlot of exponential spiral]

A=2 and a=0.3.

This implicitly interprets the symbolic unit vectors as those for r and theta in the plane as given in the documentation of [`PolarPlot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PolarPlot.html).

Simply calculate

```
r.r=A^2 Exp[2 a t]
```

making use of the properties of squared unit vectors to equal one. And put the square root of the result into `PolarPlot`.

This can look really nice:

```
PolarPlot[.2 Exp[.13 \[Theta]], {\[Theta], 0, 4 Pi}, 
 PlotStyle -> Thick, 
 ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y, \[Theta]}, Hue[\[Theta]/(2 Pi)]], 
 ColorFunctionScaling -> False]
```

[image: PolarPlot of exponential spiral]